# How to Map Reference to Object with Composite Key ID

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, legacy

Suppose I have the following:

```
class ObjectA implements Serializable {
    Foo foo
    String objectType

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id composite: ['foo', 'objectType']
        foo column: 'foo'
        objectType column: 'objecttype'
    }
}
```

Now, I need to reference this object from another Domain.

```
class ObjectB {
    ObjectA objectA

    columns {
       objectA{
          column name: 'foo'
          column name: 'objecttype'
       }
    }
}
```

When I try and load an ObjectB, I get the following:

```
Cannot treat multi-column property as a single-column property
```

How should I be mapping this?

Answer (score -1):

What are you attempting to do with the columns section, I only ask because I have am unfamiliar with that concept?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729629/grails-gorm-how-do-i-create-a-composite-primary-key-and-use-it-for-a-table-rela) stack overflow link may help.

But, as show in link, if you want to reference the object you should create a relationship (the one in the example is unidirectional) between the two domains.

```
class Object B {

    static hasOne[objectA:ObjectA]
    ....
}
```

There really isn't much more to it then that. You can access the fields from objectA within you views just by using ObjectBInstance.objectA.channelName.

Comment: No, it is not that simple. When dealing with composite